# Automatic Table creation - Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, sqlite

I am trying to recreate my Oracle database in SQLite using Hibernate. I have used the hbm2ddl tag value as "create". Still my SQLite DB is not getting created. Could someone please help me with this ? I have posted below my cfg.xml file

```
<!-- language: xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="">
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"> org.sqlite.JDBC  </property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username"></property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect </property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:resources/newdb.db</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_updates">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
  <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:resources/newdb.db</property>
```

with:

```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlite:resources/newdb.db</property>
```

You're missing to write `hibernate` in the property.

And add this line:

```
  <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

In case you have entity write them like this:

```
  <mapping class="path.to.your.Entity"/>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But it still doesn't solve my problem. And as far as my entities are concerned, I generate them automatically after connecting with the Oracle database. So, I don't add them in the cfg.xml file. Instead I add the auto-generated .hbm.xml file as a resource to the configuration object after creating it during runtime.

Comment: @BB8 are you  created your entity why you interessting to create

Comment: I want to create a embedded database(SQLite) similar to my production database schema every time I run my tool. To get the updated POJO classes I recreate them everytime from production.  My issue is with creating the embedded database from the newly generated POJO classes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, 
First the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence-unit name="foo-persist" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.this.is.entity.foo</class>
    <class>com.this.is.entity.foo</class>
    <class>com.this.is.entity.foo</class>
    <jta-data-source>foo-persist</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>  
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Second is the following class which contains the properties needed by the persistence-unit:

```
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class CommonService { 
EntityManager em;
public static final String PERSISTENT_UNIT = "foo-persist"; 
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Config.PERSISTENT_UNIT);
Map properties = new HashMap();

public Map getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager()  {

    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "");        
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "org.sqlite.JDBC");
    properties.put("eclipselink.logging.level", "OFF");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "create");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source", "META-INF/script.sql");
    properties.put("javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source", "META-INF/script.sql");
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Config.PERSISTENT_UNIT, properties);
    return em = (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager(); 
}
 }
```